# How to draw "non-function" graph: f(x) = g(y)

Tags: math, graphic

I want to know is there any fast way to draw a graph of a "non-function" curve. For example

```
x^2+3x = y^3-4y+1
```

I know for normal function, like y=x^2, we can iterate x and calculate y, then draw the points. But for non-function curve, it will take a lot of times to iterate x, then solve function of y (using Newton method or alike). So please suggest me the correct way to draw them.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: The term “[algebraic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve)” might be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no "generic" way except for the method you describe yourself: iterate over one variable and solve for the other.

## Complications

Note that you have to be careful to find *all* solutions, not just *a* solution. This is a major stumbling block in creating a working general algorithm.

Another stumbling block is the singularity points: when `f'(x)=0`, you will want to solve for `y` and, vice versa, when `g'(y)=0`, you will want to solve for `x`. What if *both* are 0 at the same time? You will need to do some paper-and-pencil analysis.

## Special Cases

There are some problem-specific simplifications though.

In your specific case the equation for `x` is [quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation), so a well known simple closed formula exists. This means that iterating over `y` and solving for `x` is easier. (The equation for `y` is [cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), so a less well known and much more complicated formula exist too).

Another way is to find a [parametric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) representation of your curve (e.g., `x^2+y^2=1` is equivalent to `x=cos(t); y=sin(t); 0<=t<2*pi`).